# Changing Laravel route based on cookie value

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, cookies

On my site I have a navigation bar. Here is a sample/portion of it:

```
<li><a class="tier1Nav2" id="tier1Nav2Item1" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=graphic','orderBy=date']) }}">Graphic Design</a>
    <ul class="dropDownNav" id="dropDownNav1">
        <div class="rightSideDrop"><div id="dropImg1" class="dropImg">{!! Html::image('images/nav/placeholder.png'); !!}</div></div>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item1" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=interface','orderBy=date']) }}">Interface Design</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item2" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=web','orderBy=date']) }}">Web Layouts</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item3" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=illustration','orderBy=date']) }}">Illustrations</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item4" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=brush','orderBy=date']) }}">Brushes</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item5" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=typography','orderBy=date']) }}">Typography</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item6" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=identity','orderBy=date']) }}">Identity & Branding</a></li>
        <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item7" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=vector','orderBy=date']) }}">Vector Art</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
```

These links are routed to the controller `BrowseController.php`.

However, there is a similar controller, `FullViewBrowseController.php`.

When a user is on a browse page, he can switch to the fullview version of that page. This will also set a cookie (and vice versa).

```
$(document).on('click','.wall-of-thumbs-link', function(){
    setCookie("commendme_browse_view", "thumb_view", 365);
}); 

$(document).on('click','.full-view-link', function(){
    setCookie("commendme_browse_view", "full_view", 365);
});
```

I want this navagation bar's links to route to different controllers based on this cookie's value. In other words, by default I want the links to show the regular browse controller, as well as if the cookie is set to `"thumb_view"`. Like earlier, for example:

```
<li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item1" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=interface','orderBy=date']) }}">Interface Design</a></li>
```

However, if the cookie is set to `"fullview_view"`, I want these links to route through the `FullViewBrowseController.php`, like so:

```
<li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item1" href="{{ route('browse.fullview.results', ['query=interface','orderBy=date']) }}">Interface Design</a></li>
```

There are about two dozen links in total in the nav bar like these, so I'm not sure which solution would be best.

One option would be to have 2 navbars, one with fullview links and one with regular links, both hidden, and using .show() to unhide the appropriate one based on the cookie's value. But I feel that isn't very elegant.

Any suggestions?

Comment: use attr() to set the attribute

Comment: That doesn't really help me here...

Comment: Unless you're creating a modern, dynamic-UI web application, I'd forget about the JS cookie and stick to the server-side. You could set the cookie via Laravel with the `Cookie` facade. This would make it possible to serve the correct links (or navbar) based on the cookie value when the views are rendered. For the navigation, you could create a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers) to centralize the cookie-navigation logic.

Comment: @lesssugar your answer is exactly what I am looking for, but I don't know how to do that. I tired to store and get cookies from route, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your Question, You want to Show different Routes according to Cookie Value. Here is the Quick Solution.

```
@if(isset($_COOKIE['commendme_browse_view']) and $_COOKIE['commendme_browse_view'] == 'full_view')
    <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item1" href="{{ route('browse.fullview.results', ['query=interface','orderBy=date']) }}">Interface Design</a></li>
    // More Links
@else
    <li class="ddNavItem"><a id="ddNav1Item1" href="{{ route('browse.results', ['query=interface','orderBy=date']) }}">Interface Design</a></li>
    // More Links
@endif
```

This Code will show `thumb_view` by Default, and if the user has Selected `full_view`, It will show Full View.

Let me know if it works!

**Update:** The only Drawback of using this method is if you are Removing Some Links from Navbar, You have to Remove them from both the sections. Same for Editing the Links.